# How to cut off end in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

I have this code in my Twig template:

```
    <h2><a href="{{ wp.get_permalink(property.ID) }}">
            {% if property.meta._property_title.0 %}
                {{ property.meta._property_title.0 }}
            {% else %}
                {{ property.post_title }}
            {% endif %}
       </a></h2>
```

property.post_title will look like **Some words / Other words / More words / 123**

What I want to do is to display only the part until the first slash, so in this case only **Some words**

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (if you do not want to declare a new twig variable).

```
{{ property.post_title|split('/')[0] }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Twig has the function, to split a string into array by your own delimiter:

```
{% set foo = "one,two,three"|split(',') %}
```

You can create a new var, and split on `"/"`:

```
{% set splits = property.post_title|split('/') %}
```

Now you have a simple array, and can print the first part:

```
 <h2><a href="{{ wp.get_permalink(property.ID) }}">
        {% if property.meta._property_title.0 %}
            {{ property.meta._property_title.0 }}
        {% else %}
            {{ splits.0 }}
        {% endif %}
 </a></h2>
```

See http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html for more.